# wxPython: How Come the Panel is Missing TextCtrl and Button When Run?

Tags: python, wxpython

I have a simple password generator:

```
import wx, string, secrets

def main():
    
    app = wx.App()
    
    class PwdGenFrame(wx.Frame):
        
        pnl = wx.Panel()
        
        def __init__(self, *args, **kw):
            super().__init__(*args, **kw)
            self.makeMenuBar()
            self.CreateStatusBar()
            self.SetStatusText('Version 0.10')
                
        def makeMenuBar(self):
            fileMenu = wx.Menu()
            exitItem = fileMenu.Append(wx.ID_EXIT)
            menuBar = wx.MenuBar()
            self.SetMenuBar(menuBar)
            self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.OnExit, exitItem)
            
            menuBar.Append(fileMenu, "&File")
        
        def OnExit(self, event):
            self.Close(True)

        pwd_length_input = wx.TextCtrl(pnl, -1, 'Enter the length of the password you would like')
        pwd_length_input.SetInitialSize(pwd_length_input.GetSizeFromTextSize(pwd_length_input.GetTextExtent('Enter the length of the password you would like')))
        button = wx.Button(pnl, -1, 'Generate')
        frame_output = wx.TextCtrl(pnl, -1, '', style=wx.TE_READONLY)
        
        def gen_pwd(self, event):
            lower_case = string.ascii_lowercase; upper_case = string.ascii_uppercase; numbers = string.digits; characters = string.punctuation; 
            concoctaneted_list = lower_case + upper_case + numbers + characters
            password_length = self.pwd_length_input.GetValue()
            
            while True:
                generated_password = ''
                try:
                    if password_length < 8:
                        print('Minimum password length is 8 characters.')
                        password_length = int(input('Enter the length of the password you would like: '))
                finally:
                    for i in range(password_length):
                        generated_password += ''.join(secrets.choice(concoctaneted_list))
                        
                    if (sum(letter in lower_case for letter in generated_password)>=2) and (sum(letter in upper_case for letter in generated_password)>=2) and (sum(num in numbers for num in generated_password)>=2) and (sum(c in characters for c in generated_password)>=2):
                            break
                
                self.frame_output.SetValue(generated_password)
        
        button.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, gen_pwd)

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(pwd_length_input, 0, wx.EXPAND|wx.ALL, 10)
        sizer.Add(button, 0, wx.EXPAND|wx.ALL, 10)
        sizer.Add(frame_output, 0, wx.EXPAND|wx.ALL, 10)
        pnl.SetSizer(sizer)
    
    frm = PwdGenFrame(None, title='Password Generator', size=wx.Size(600, 300))
    frm.Show(); frm.CenterOnScreen(); app.MainLoop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

When I run the program this window appears:
[Empty Panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KIkD0.png)

What is expected is 2 `wx.TextCtrl` boxes and a `wx.Button` button in between the boxes. But I'm not sure why it isn't working.

In the [documentation](https://wxpython.org/pages/overview/) `wx.Panel(self)` appears in the `__init__` method, but when I tried that, I wasn't able to assign the `wx.TextCtrl` nor the `wx.Button`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like everything needs to be under `__init__` in order to work:

```
import wx, secrets, string

class PwdGenFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kw):
        super().__init__(*args, **kw)
        
        pnl = wx.Panel(self)
        
        pwdLength = wx.TextCtrl(pnl, value='Enter the length of the password you would like to generate')
        pwdLength.SetInitialSize(pwdLength.GetSizeFromTextSize(pwdLength.GetTextExtent('Enter the length of the password you would like to generate')))
        
        makePwd = wx.Button(pnl, -1, 'Generate')
        
        showPwd = wx.TextCtrl(pnl, -1, style=wx.TE_READONLY)
        
        def pwdGenMethod(event):
            password_length = int(pwdLength.GetValue())
            
            lower_case = string.ascii_lowercase; upper_case = string.ascii_uppercase; numbers = string.digits; characters = string.punctuation
            concoctaneted_list = lower_case + upper_case + numbers + characters
            
            while True:
                generated_password = ''
                try:
                    if password_length < 8:
                        print('Minimum password length is 8 characters.')
                        password_length = int(input('Enter the length of the password you would like: '))
                finally:
                    for i in range(password_length):
                        generated_password += ''.join(secrets.choice(concoctaneted_list))
                        
                    if (sum(letter in lower_case for letter in generated_password)>=2) and (sum(letter in upper_case for letter in generated_password)>=2) and (sum(num in numbers for num in generated_password)>=2) and (sum(c in characters for c in generated_password)>=2):
                            break
                
                showPwd.SetValue(generated_password)
            pass
        
        makePwd.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, pwdGenMethod)
        
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(pwdLength, 0, wx.EXPAND|wx.ALL, 10)
        sizer.Add(makePwd, 0, wx.EXPAND|wx.ALL, 10)
        sizer.Add(showPwd, 0, wx.EXPAND|wx.ALL, 10)
        pnl.SetSizer(sizer)
        
        self.makeMenuBar()
        
        self.CreateStatusBar()
        self.SetStatusText('Version 0.12')
        pass
    
    def makeMenuBar(self):
        fileMenu = wx.Menu()
        exitItem = fileMenu.Append(wx.ID_EXIT)
        
        menuBar = wx.MenuBar()
        menuBar.Append(fileMenu, '&File')
        
        self.SetMenuBar(menuBar)
        
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.onExit, exitItem)
        pass
    
    def onExit(self, event):
        self.Close(True)
    pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App()
    frm = PwdGenFrame(None, title='Password Generator')
    frm.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 0):

This might get you closer to where you want to be and be a little more `standard`.

Best bet is to look at the code side-by-side, to see where I've made changes. There are a few of them. :)

```
import wx
import string
import secrets

class PwdGenFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, id=wx.ID_ANY):
        wx.Frame.__init__ (self, parent, title='Password Generator')
        self.makeMenuBar()
        self.CreateStatusBar()
        self.SetStatusText('Version 0.10')

        pnl = wx.Panel(self)

        self.pwd_length_input = wx.TextCtrl(pnl, -1, 'Enter the length of the password you would like')
        self.pwd_length_input.SetInitialSize(self.pwd_length_input.GetSizeFromTextSize(self.pwd_length_input.GetTextExtent('Enter the length of the password you would like')))
        self.button = wx.Button(pnl, -1, 'Generate')
        self.frame_output = wx.TextCtrl(pnl, -1, '', style=wx.TE_READONLY)

        self.button.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.gen_pwd)

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(self.pwd_length_input, 0, wx.EXPAND|wx.ALL, 10)
        sizer.Add(self.button, 0, wx.EXPAND|wx.ALL, 10)
        sizer.Add(self.frame_output, 0, wx.EXPAND|wx.ALL, 10)
        pnl.SetSizer(sizer)

        self.Show()
        self.CenterOnScreen()

    def gen_pwd(self, event):
        lower_case = string.ascii_lowercase; upper_case = string.ascii_uppercase; numbers = string.digits; characters = string.punctuation;
        concoctaneted_list = lower_case + upper_case + numbers + characters
        try:
            password_length = int(self.pwd_length_input.GetValue())
        except Exception:
            return

        generated_password = ''
        while not generated_password:
            try:
                if password_length < 8:
                    wx.MessageBox('Minimum password length is 8 characters\nTry again!', 'Error', wx.OK | wx.ICON_INFORMATION)
                    generated_password = "Invalid input"
                    continue
            finally:
                if password_length < 8:
                    continue
                for i in range(password_length):
                    generated_password += ''.join(secrets.choice(concoctaneted_list))

                if (sum(letter in lower_case for letter in generated_password)>=2) and \
                   (sum(letter in upper_case for letter in generated_password)>=2) and \
                   (sum(num in numbers for num in generated_password)>=2) and \
                   (sum(c in characters for c in generated_password)>=2):
                            break
        self.frame_output.SetValue(generated_password)

    def makeMenuBar(self):
        fileMenu = wx.Menu()
        exitItem = fileMenu.Append(wx.ID_EXIT)
        menuBar = wx.MenuBar()
        self.SetMenuBar(menuBar)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.OnExit, exitItem)
        menuBar.Append(fileMenu, "&File")

    def OnExit(self, event):
        self.Close(True)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App()
    frm = PwdGenFrame(None)
    app.MainLoop()
```

Best of luck.

[image]